# Remove a line contains something in VB.Net

Tags: vb.net

in that case how can I change this line to be "" or delete it?

```
 For Each Line As String In TxtListScanTxt.Lines
            If (Line.Contains("{ LstScan = , DrwR2 = 0000000000 }")) Then
                Line.Remove(Line)
            End If
        Next
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```vb
TxtListScanTxt.Lines = TxtListScanTxt.Lines.Where( _
    Function(line) Not line.Contains("{ LstScan = , DrwR2 = 0000000000 }") _
).ToArray()
```